# Python paho.mqtt with SOCKS proxy

Tags: python, mqtt, socks

My organisation has an enterprise FW and a SOCKS proxy to allow bypassing it. I need to be able to use MQTT with an external server.
I am able to use PySocks in a python script (to monkey patch) but when I try using paho.mqtt it breaks.

Is there an MQTT lib that allowes using SOCKS? Is there another way for to go at it?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import socket
import socks
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
socks.set_default_proxy(socks.SOCKS5,"my-proxy",1080)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))
client.subscribe("$SYS/#")
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload))
client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.connect("iot.eclipse.org", 1883, 60)
client.loop_forever()
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./yo.py", line 20, in <module>
    client = mqtt.Client()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 508, in
__init__
    self._sockpairR, self._sockpairW = _socketpair_compat()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 277, in
_socketpair_compat
    sock1.connect(("127.0.0.1", port))   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/socks.py", line 96, in wrapper
    return function(*args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/socks.py", line 813, in connect
    negotiate(self, dest_addr, dest_port)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/socks.py", line 477, in
_negotiate_SOCKS5
    CONNECT, dest_addr)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/socks.py", line 552, in
_SOCKS5_request
    raise SOCKS5Error("{0:#04x}: {1}".format(status, error)) socks.SOCKS5Error: 0x01: General SOCKS server failure
```

Comment: Is the socks proxy really running on localhost (127.0.0.1) or did you edit the error?

Answer (score -1):

I think paho python has socks support now as mentioned in the Github url:

[paho python setup.py extras](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/blob/master/setup.py)

Please look at proxy_set method in [client.py](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/blob/master/src/paho/mqtt/client.py)

Comment: Changing how the client loop is started isn't going to change anything since the failure is in the Client constructor code before the client loop is reached.

Comment: Rather than editing the answer to match what I pointed out, you could just delete it. Because as it is now, without looking at the edit history there is no context and the answer adds nothing useful

Comment: You can always delete your own posts